# show/hide div by clicking image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to be able to click on images to show/hide a div (with text). I've got this working for one image, but I have multiple images that need to toggle text.

The javascript code

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $("slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

The HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="show_hide"><img src="image.jpg"></a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

So this works, but it only works for one image+div. I want to have a second image and div, but using the same `slidingDiv` class and then clicking the second image to toggle the second div obviously toggles both divs.

So how can I get two images to toggle their own div, instead of toggling both divs at the same time when clicking one of the two images?

Comment: You are missing the selector type.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add `"."` in `$("slidingDiv").slideToggle();`

You can also use this

**[JsFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/u6d876oL/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
          
         //$(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
         var isvisible = $(this).next('.slidingDiv').is(':visible');
      
         if ( isvisible ) {
           $(this).next('.slidingDiv').hide();
         } else{
           $(this).next('.slidingDiv').show(); 
         }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" class="show_hide"><img src="image.jpg" alt="img"/></a>
<div class="slidingDiv">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
$("slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

to

```
$(this).next(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/r9j6L3n7/)**

`$(".slidingDiv")`, as you noticed, selects all elements with the slidingDiv class. To select the slidingDiv class *relative* to the element you click on, use `this` to refer to the element being clicked on, and then `.next(".slidingDiv")` to select the next element as long as it has the class slidingDiv.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.show_hide').click(function(e) {
    $(e.target).parent().next('.slidingDiv').slideToggle();
});
```

`e.target` will give you the source DOM element for `click event`.

Comment: But that's not the element he wants to toggle.

Comment: @j08691 how about now?

Comment: Why don't you test it and see?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap both in a same div and do the next steps:

1. find the parent of the image with .parent()
2. find the .slidingDiv of the parent with .find()
3. hide/show the .slidingDiv with .slideToggle()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".slidingDiv").hide();
    $(".show_hide").show();

    $('.show_hide').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().find(".slidingDiv").slideToggle();
    });

});
```

```css
.fleft{
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="fleft"> <!-- This is the parent div -->
  <a href="#" class="show_hide"><img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></a>
  <div class="slidingDiv">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fleft"> <!-- This is the parent div -->
  <a href="#" class="show_hide"><img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></a>
  <div class="slidingDiv">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="fleft"> <!-- This is the parent div -->
  <a href="#" class="show_hide"><img style="width:100px;height:100px" src="http://www.online-image-editor.com//styles/2014/images/example_image.png"></a>
  <div class="slidingDiv">
    <h2>Title</h2>
    <p>text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How can I position the divs next to each other without them moving when I toggle the text? Because that's what keeps happening when I use `float: left` on both.

Comment: I change the code to answer your comment. `float: left` on the parent div and not in the slidingDiv. Thats what you need?

Comment: That's what I already tried and they do position next to each other, but when I click on the first image, the second image moves to underneath the first image.

Comment: Attach a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) with the code and maybe I can help you.