# How should I expand a div using jquery when clicked on image?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm working on an image grid. Here is my HTML code:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of items$|async">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="{{item.link}}" height="200px">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is whenever I click on an image: a div should expand just like similar to Google image. How should I achieve it using jquery?

I earlier tried to implement this feature using pure CSS but after that what was happening was, when I clicked on any image the div was expanding in each row. It was not behaving like google images do. It would be great if someone can help me out in this.

Comment: paste code for the `div which should expand` and paste the `css` you early used.So we can help you as per your need.!

Comment: Your question is way to broad. We can't help you building a whole modal, as you said _like on google_.

Comment: @eisbehr, Not the whole modal. I mean just creating a expandable area only not the features inside it.

Comment: Still too broad! There are so many modal tutorials and tools on the outside, so a bit of research and I'm sure you find what you want to do. And if you then have problems you can ask again ...

Comment: @eisbehr thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34931562/show-hide-div-by-clicking-image).

```js
// You can also use `$` instead of `jQuery` if you are sure that variable is
// not occupied by another library. This `$(callback)` shortcut attaches a
// callback to the DOM load event. It's the same as `$(document).ready(callback)`,
// but shorter. It passed the jQuery object to the callback so we can safely
// use `$` inside of the callback.
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.posts').on('click', '.post-toggle', function() {
    // This is called a delegated event. The handler is attached to
    // the `<ul class="posts">`, so you only need one event handler.
    // But the callback is only executed if `<li class="post">` is in
    // the event chain. It's not only more efficient with memory but
    // also works automagically if posts get added or deleted.

    // `this` is the targetted element, the `post-toggle`. It's a normal
    // DOM element object so we convert it to a jQuery object with
    // `$(this)`.

    // `closest('.post')` finds the closest ancestor with class `post`.

    // `find('.post-content')` finds the closes descendant with class `post-content`.

    // `toggle()` toggles visibility using the `display` property.
    $(this).closest('.post').find('.post-content').toggle();
  });
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: '';
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}

.post {
  margin: 0 0 1.5em;
}

.post-toggle {
  float: left;
  width: 4em;
  height: 4em;
  background: #bada55;
}

.post-content {
  display: none;
  height: 8em;
  border: 0.25em solid #bada55;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="posts">
  <li class="post clearfix">
    <div class="post-toggle"></div>
    <div class="post-content"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="post clearfix">
    <div class="post-toggle"></div>
    <div class="post-content"></div>
  </li>
  <li class="post clearfix">
    <div class="post-toggle"></div>
    <div class="post-content"></div>
  </li>
</ul>
```